# Loading results from a category malfunction

Tags: php, mysql

i am using this code to retrieve all posts from a speciefic category. This code appears the first 20 results and then when a user scroll the page to the bottom it loads next 20 results and so on. Unfortunately when i click on a certain category the first 20 results are right, but the next results are mixed from other categories. Below is the code i use. What am i doing wrong ??

```
    function category($category="''") {
    $userID = false;
    $order = false;
    $limit = $this->config->item('post_load_limit');
    $page = $this->uri->segment(4, 1);
    $nextOffset = ($page -1) * $limit;
    $nextPage = $page +1;
    $sql = "SELECT *
                FROM
                    posts";
    if ($category)
        $sql .= ' WHERE
                    album_id in (SELECT id
                FROM
                    album
                WHERE
                    category ="'.$category.'")';
    if ($order) {
        $sql .= " ORDER BY
                    '$order'";
    } else {

        $sql .= " ORDER BY time DESC";
    }
    $sql .= " LIMIT $nextOffset,$limit";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        $row = $query->result();
    }
    if (!empty($row))
        $data['row'] = $row;
    else
        $data['row'] = false;
    $data['title'] = 'Welcome';
```

Thanks again for your valuable help!

Comment: _and then when a user scroll the page to the bottom it loads next 20 results and so on_ This must be done with `JavaScript`, can you please paste here the `JavaScript` code you use for loading the next results?

Comment: How are you calling your function and passing the category?

Comment: Which PHP framework are you using here? You're not [properly escaping your SQL values](http://bobby-tables.com/) like `$category`. You must be extremely careful when doing this or there could be very nasty consequences.